# How can i make the image grow to a certain percentage?

Tags: html

I never programmed in `html` or have done web tasks before but currently i'm using a git repo where the project is client server therefore i have to work with his code to my requirements, part of it is html and the issue i have is my images are too big `5400x3601` the small text on the images is no longer readable. I identified the part responsible of that due to trial and error :

```
 <div style="overflow: scroll">
        <canvas id="canvas" style="width:100%; height:80%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></canvas>
    </div>
```

by changing width and style to 300% each i have got the result i want, but had issues with images who's size is like `951x663` as they fitted well on the default image without the need to oversize their looks .
How can i solve that issue?

Comment: you should fix your initial images so they are optimised for web (and sized consistently) - serving such a large image will make your web page very slow

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether they need to keep aspect ratio or not, but assuming that doesn't matter you could try setting `max-width` and/or `max-height` instead of `width` and `height`. That will keep the elements to a maximum size of whatever you set, but if they are smaller, they'll just fill the space they need.

Comment: Adjusting the code sample i added in my question and adding it as answer as well could be helpful so i could actually test that.